# QML ListModel.onRowsAboutToBeRemoved arguments

Tags: qt, listview, qml, listmodel

I'd like to know the arguments for the automatically-generated QML function onRowsAboutToBeRemoved (of the ListModel component.) Specifically, I need to know what the index value is called so I can do operations on the row about to be removed before the action takes place.

Comment: When in doubt, look for the sources, [here it is](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/qml/types/qqmllistmodel_p.h#n162). Mind that if you are using `WorkerScript` the behaviour is bugged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A QML signal handler method name is basically the signal name with "on" prefixed and the first letter of the signal name uppercased.

In your case that would lead us to a signal named `rowsAboutToBeRemoved`

You will find its documentation in the base class for Qt models: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsAboutToBeRemoved

The argument names are therefore `parent`, `first` and `last`